# How can I create the current Year/Month/Day folder dynamically in the Azure Data Factory pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using copy activity to send data to Azure Data Lake Gen2. I need to create a Year/Month/Day folder dynamically.

```
file_1.csv
file_2.csv
file_3.csv
.
-
-
file_9.csv
```

My question: how can I Create a Year/Month/Day folder dynamically transferring from one container to another container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following procedure for getting **Year/Month/Day** folder dynamically.

In my storage account, these are the files.

[image]

- Create a copy activity with wild card path.

[image]

Then, go to sink -> Open sink dataset and Create dataset parameter with the name `folder`.

[image]

Go to connection, and added this dynamic content: `@dataset().folder`

[image]

*Now, add this dynamic content to the dataset properties value:*

```
@concat(formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy'), '/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd'),'/')
```

[image]

***Pipeline successfully executed and got this output :***

[image]